# DS Fault Message: Error in 'createProcessedPreparedStatement' in WSO2 DataService

Tags: mysql, sql, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have created a Dataservice in WSO2 to execute SQL Query `TRUNCATE TABLE Student` and expose it as an API , but i got this error

> [2022-12-07 16:33:57,222] ERROR {DBInOnlyMessageReceiver} - Error in
> in-only message receiver DS Fault Message: Error in DS non result
> invoke. DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR Nested Exception:-
> javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in
> 'SQLQuery.processStoredProcQuery': DS Fault Message: Error in
> 'createProcessedPreparedStatement' DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR Nested
> Exception:- java.sql.SQLException: Unable to retrieve metadata for
> procedure.
>
> DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR Source Data Service:- Name: RADMINDataService
> Location:
> /home/master/Downloads/IntegrationStudio/runtime/microesb/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1670427210936TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car/RADMINDataService_1.0.0/RADMINDataService-1.0.0.dbs
> Description: Exposing the radmin data service as a REST service
> Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/json_sample
> Current Request Name: _gettruncatenumseq Current Params: {} Nested
> Exception:- DS Fault Message: Error in
> 'createProcessedPreparedStatement' DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR Nested
> Exception:- java.sql.SQLException: Unable to retrieve metadata for
> procedure.
>
> at
> org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processSingleRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:117)
> at
> org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:66)
> at
> org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:358)
> at
> org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:40)
> at
> org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DBInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:52)
> at
> org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
> at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
> at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:376)
> at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:190)
> at
> org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
> javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in
> 'SQLQuery.processStoredProcQuery': DS Fault Message: Error in
> 'createProcessedPreparedStatement' DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR Nested
> Exception:- java.sql.SQLException: Unable to retrieve metadata for
> procedure.

This is my configuration file

> ```
> <query id="truncatenum" useConfig="mysql">
> <sql><![CDATA[TRUNCATE TABLE Student]]></sql> 
> </query>
> <resource method="GET" path="truncatenum">
> <description />
> <call-query href="truncatenum"/>
> </resource>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error is caused by the code snippet you shared. The following seems correct.

```xml
<query id="truncatenum" useConfig="mysql">
<sql><![CDATA[TRUNCATE TABLE Student]]></sql> 
</query>
<resource method="GET" path="truncatenum">
<description />
<call-query href="truncatenum"/>
</resource>
```

Probably one of the queries you have doesn't match the input parameters you are providing. Hence double check all the other queries you have.

---

**Update**

You are correct the `TRUNCATE` query is executed as a `STOREDPROC`. I had a closer look at the [source-code](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/blob/master/components/data/data-services/org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/micro/integrator/dataservices/core/description/query/SQLQuery.java#L706) and it seems if the QUERY String doesn't start with one of the following it's inferred as a `STOREDPROC`. This is definitely a bug in WSO2.

[image]

The weird thing is, in my case the TRUNCATE query is executed as a Stored Procedure successfully. So I assume there is a difference in your Dataeervice from the one I'm trying. Can you create the following Dataservice as it is and try it out? (Just change the connection parameters)

**Dataservice**

```xml
<data name="RESTDataService" serviceNamespace="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/json_sample" transports="http https">
  <description>Exposing the data service as a REST service.</description>
  <config id="default">
    <property name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_db</property>
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.user">root</property>
    <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.password">root123456</property>
  </config>
  <resource method="GET" path="truncatenum">
    <description />
    <call-query href="truncatenum" />
  </resource>
  <query id="truncatenum" useConfig="default">
    <sql><![CDATA[TRUNCATE TABLE students]]></sql>
  </query>
</data>
```

**Request**

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8290/services/RESTDataService/truncatenum'
```

If you still get the error. Please enable DEBUG logs for the package `org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices` and share the logs.

Comment: I use get method to execute Truncate table query . so wso2 didn't understade TRUNCATE and he think that i'm going to call a stored procedure .

Comment: @OussamaNairi are you on MySQL?

Comment: yes, I'm using MYSQL

Comment: @OussamaNairi I actually tested this on MYSQL and it worked for me. Can you share the  Full stacktrace you are getting?

Comment: I have updated my question with the stacktrace i got .

Comment: @OussamaNairi I've updated the answer have a look.